# Convert xml string to json file (with option to pretty print) using Jackson

Tags: java, xml, json, jackson

I've been searching for a good, fast library to convert xml to json. I've settled on Jackson. Does anyone have any simple examples on how to go about doing so? I tried looking through the documentation, but it is incredibly detailed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickest way to convert XML to JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java)

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xml).