# xml to json conversion issue in java, 1st leading zero discarded fom string

Tags: java, xml, json

My xml contains attribute value "0123" which I want to treat as string,
after conversion from xml to json as per following code
leading zero gets discarded from attribute value.

Used classes

```
import org.jdom.Attribute;
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.output.Format;
import org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
```

//Covert xml to json

```
    org.jdom.Document jdomDocument = new Document();
    org.jdom.Element Attribute = new org.jdom.Element("Attribute");
    jdomDocument.setRootElement(Attribute);

    org.jdom.Element valueElement = new  org.jdom.Element("Value");
    valueElement.setText(getValue()); // "0123"
   // getValue() return anything like boolean,string,long,date, time etc..

     root.addContent(valueElement);
    String xmlval = new    XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat()).outputString(jdomDocument);
    JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xmlval);
    String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(4);
```

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: @Qwerky Question edited

Comment: Clearly this library is doing some guesswork to try and guess the most suitable JSON data type to use. It's not clear whether you actually want to treat 0123 as a string or as a number. If you want it as a number, it has to be 123 rather than 0123, because JSON doesn't allow a leading zero: that's because of the ancient and horrible tradition in C and Java and JS of treating numbers starting with a zero as octal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works :)

Added value in CDATA section so while conversion from xml to json value display as it is

```
   org.jdom.Element valueElement = new  org.jdom.Element("Value");
    org.jdom.CDATA cdata = new org.jdom.CDATA(getValue());
    valueElement.setText(cdata );
```

Answer (score 2):

looking at the [code for XML.java](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/XML.java) - in particular the stringToValue method which does

```
"Try to convert a string into a number, boolean, or null".
```

The code is below - you can see it tries to parse as a number first, in which case it will trim the leading zeros.  To test you could try adding a non-numeric character in your string - I think it would then preserve the leading zeros.

It looks like the behaviour you're seeing is baked into the library.
Which is not great, even though the docs for the function toJSONObject do warn

```
"Some information may be lost in this transformation because JSON is a data format and XML is a document format"
```

teh codez :

```
// If it might be a number, try converting it. If that doesn't work,
// return the string.

        try {
            char initial = string.charAt(0);
            boolean negative = false;
            if (initial == '-') {
                initial = string.charAt(1);
                negative = true;
            }
            if (initial == '0' && string.charAt(negative ? 2 : 1) == '0') {
                return string;
            }
            if ((initial >= '0' && initial <= '9')) {
                if (string.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
                    return Double.valueOf(string);
                } else if (string.indexOf('e') < 0 && string.indexOf('E') < 0) {
                    Long myLong = new Long(string);
                    if (myLong.longValue() == myLong.intValue()) {
                        return new Integer(myLong.intValue());
                    } else {
                        return myLong;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
```

EDIT :
this looks like a bug in the library.  I believe it should use

```
(negative ? 1 : 0)
```

because the current behaviour wrongly interprets a value with a single leading zero as being a number.  It correctly recognizes two or more leading zeros as being a string, as confirmed by the asker.

Comment: Please see updated question & What changes I need to do in my code ?

Comment: try "0123A" instead, to check this is really the problem

Comment: @ Graham Griffiths if I append 'A' then I am getting "0123A" in jsonString. I want "0123" only.

Comment: to be honest, it looks like a bug in this library code, I think it should be (negative ? 1 : 0) in which case it would always consider a leading zero to mean a string.  With the code as it is, I think it will take two leading zeros to interpret it as a string - it's worth trying this by using "00123" in your code.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :) if xml value="00123" then getting json value "00123".

Comment: I think you have come across a bug in the library, which you could report via this page : http://www.json.org/java/  it seems that when it gets a single leading zero, it will treat the value as a number instead of a string (although it will deal correctly with two or more leading zeros)

Comment: Graham Griffiths Reported problem to json.org . Any workaround to solve this issue?

Comment: Use a different JSON library? Otherwise you would have to modify the values of the strings passed in - which seems bad, since you want to pass through the exact original value.  Sorry, no better suggestions.

Comment: @ Graham Griffiths I just want to know what is "e" / "E" in string ?

Comment: e / E is for scientific notation 1.4e-9