# Leading zero getting truncated while XML converted into JSON

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I'm using following code for converting XML value into JSON String but while its getting converted leading zeros from all the values getting truncated.

```
String xmlString = "<root><a>AAA</a><b>bbb</b><c>123</c><d>000.345</d><e>01122334455</e><postCode>028</postCode></root>"; 
JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString); 
String e = jsonObj.getJSONObject("root").getString("e");
```

JSON Output

```
{
  "root": {
    "a": "AAA",
    "b": "bbb",
    "c": "123",
    "d": "0.345",
    "e": "1122334455",
    "postCode": "28"
  }
}
```

I want `e` value as `01122334455` but it is returning 1122334455.

Is there any other library to fix this issue or any solution for this.

**Note:** I can not change my server side code.

Comment: post this method code `XML.toJSONObject(xmlString)` or is it a lib?

Comment: @bharat this is library code for `java-json`

Comment: How are you getting e? we see that you just have the object.. but have you dumped the entire object of jsonObj?

Comment: okay let me update my question @JoxTraex

Comment: I mean.. literally post what is inside of jsonObject as well and also posting a link to the documentation of the code would be helpful. is this YOUR library or is it a standard library?

Comment: @JoxTraex see updated post

Comment: If the library is stripping out the 0.. you could try putting the number in quotes "xxxx" and then try that

Comment: @Amy basically, I think the library checks whether its a integer or double at first, if it satisfies then converts them to integer or double otherwise as string.

Comment: @JoxTraex that's what I have mentioned in my question I can not change my server side code that means I can't change my XML string.

Comment: @NigamPatro That is the my question is there any other library to do this or any solution in this library?

Comment: `XML.toJSONObject` is treating `e` as int value (as it is a int ) but you need to tell get that treat `e` as string value.

Comment: @bharat how? Any example code?

Comment: @Amy go through this library, and check if not modify the library code according to requirement. https://github.com/pareshmutha/XMLToJsonConverterUsingJAVA

Comment: `XML` what is this lib. provide the link if you have..

Comment: @bharat `org.json.XML` this is the package name.

Comment: That is kind of odd that a library would do datatype checking when its not explicitly mentioned.. especially if you're calling get string.. weird

Comment: look like server is your last option.. and XML lib doesn't provide more customization..

Comment: which version of org.json are you using?

Comment: @SachinGupta version 1.0

Comment: I have just tried your code with this version, and its working fine.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160212

Comment: @SachinGupta I'm using eclipes

Comment: I think this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121714/xml-to-json-conversion-issue-in-java-1st-leading-zero-discarded-fom-string

Comment: @VivekMishra I have already tried this. But in that post Author have static value.

Comment: @SachinGupta when I imported given lib into my project it getting conflict with android existing package.

Comment: @SachinGupta Thank you! working like a charm. It solved my other issues too related to json conversion. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

There is [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library with static method `U.xmlToJson(xml)`. I am the maintainer of the project.

```
<root><a>AAA</a><b>bbb</b><c>123</c><d>000.345</d><e>01122334455</e><postCode>028</postCode></root>
```

Output:

```
{
  "root": {
    "a": "AAA",
    "b": "bbb",
    "c": "123",
    "d": "000.345",
    "e": "01122334455",
    "postCode": "028"
  },
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's right, I have the same problem using org.json version 20131018. Try it using the version 20140107 or above.