# Issue with boolean during conversion Xml to Json

Tags: java, json, xml

I am use this code (`org.json`) to convert XML to JSON:

```
String xml = "...<field>TRUE</field>...";
JSONObject response = XML.toJSONObject(xml); 
response.toString(); // "field": true
// but I need "field": TRUE as in xml
```

Problem is that I don't want to convert "TRUE" in boolean. I need that all fields are converted as String.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538755/how-to-convert-string-object-to-boolean-object

Comment: Nope! I ask another thing. I want to parse all field as String

Comment: This post might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121714/xml-to-json-conversion-issue-in-java-1st-leading-zero-discarded-fom-string.

Comment: were you able to resolve this @mystdeim?

Comment: Yes by fixing sources ) @Sampada

Answer (score 1):

Use the `keepStrings=false` parameter. See [here](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html?org/json/JSONML.html).

```
keepStrings If true, then values will
not be coerced into boolean or numeric values and will instead be left as strings
```

Comment: the mentioned link says 404 not found