# Preceding 0 gets removed while converting XML String to JSON Object

Tags: java, json, xml

I am facing a strange issue while converting an `XML` string into `JSON` object in `Java`. I am using `org.json.jar` for to construct the `JSON` object but if one of the `xml` tag contains number, starting with 0, that number is appearing wrong in the `JSON` object.

Could anyone please help me to sort this out please? Please find below the method I am using to convert the XML string to JSON and also I have provided the input and output.

**Method** :

```
public static String toJSON(String xml) {
    String json = null;
    try {
        JSONObject jobj = XML.toJSONObject((String)xml);
        json = jobj.toString();

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("Json Exception " + (Object)e);
    }
    return json;
}
```

**Input** :

```
<box>0X</box> <number>012345</number>
```

**Output** : 
After converting to `Json` : {"number":"5349","box":"0X"}

In `XML` I have given number as 012345 but in `JSON` it is appearing as 5349! I am expecting 012345 in JSON as well.

Any help on this will be really helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: What's 012345 in octal? (that is, interpreting 12345 as octal, what number do you get?)

Answer (score 1):

See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121714/xml-to-json-conversion-issue-in-java-1st-leading-zero-discarded-fom-string). The problem is in the implementation of `stringToValue` method in `org.json.XML`.

To disable automatic conversion to int/long which will strip out the leading zero, you can put the string value in CDATA and then it will work. e.g. the input could be:

`<box>0X</box><number><![CDATA[012345]]></number>`

Comment: If your answer is "See this other answer, here's what it says", please flag to close as a duplicate instead of answering the question.

Comment: Yes, I did flag to close it, however the answer in the other question was not too specific in recommendation, so this will help the OP nonetheless

Comment: ...Oh, I see. Then why'd you answer it?

Answer (score 0):

5349 is the Decimal Representation of the Octal 12345.

See the following lines for an illustration of potentially where you differ (using Java-7/org.json.json-20160212.jar).

```
    String regularString = "<box>0X</box> <number>012345</number>";
    System.out.println(toJSON(regularString));
    Integer anOctal = 012345;
    String withOctalString = "<box>0X</box> <number>" + anOctal + "</number>";
    System.out.println(toJSON(withOctalString));
```

Replacing the octal-style Integer/int with String should help resolve your problem.

Comment: It's not octodecimal, but octal.