# Dynamic xml into mongoDB

Tags: java, xml, json, mongodb, xslt

I'am currently working on an application (Java), and can figured out the best way to solve my issue.
I need to store data in mongoDB (with the actual data type when supported by bson format), I get the data in an xml file, and his schema (both are created dynamically at runtime, so I have no idea what's in it).

To be more specific, I didn't have any information on the fields, names of the data.
A user can create new "object" (for which there is no java class in the application) dynamically.
When a user create a new object, I receive a xml schema which describe the object.
So when a user try to add an object of this type (data are in a xml format for the new entity), I validate it with the xml schema and now I need to store the object in mogoDB.
So I need to be able to transform my xml in bson (or basic java object with mongo java driver) and back into xml after a query.

Example:

If a user want to manage people, he will define the people schema:

```
<People>
   <Name>...</Name>
   <Lastname>...</Lastname>
   <Age>...</age>
   ...
</People>
```

Here I got the xsd (a valid xsd format with all informations). Then when a user add a People I get the data like that:

```
<People>
   <Name>John</Name>
   <Lastname>Smith</Lastname>
   <Age>32</Age>
   ...
</People>
```

So i wonder if the best approach will be something like jackson: xml -> Pojo -> bson, or with XSLT xml -> json/bson (with encoding for data types). Or simply by reading the xml file and my basic java objects manually.

Did anyone have some advice on how to implements one of those solutions or better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach would seem to go XML <-> JSON
See: [Quickest way to convert XML to JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java)

Then you can go JSON <-> BSON using `com.mongodb.util.JSON` parse and serialize.

Comment: I used xlst to turn XM Linto JSON qnd then used the MongoDB java driver JSON parser to turn into BSON, that work fine. But I'm not sure about performance

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use [MongoJack](http://mongojack.org/) to magically turn your XML into something that MongoDB understands (and vice-versa)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I don't have any java class corresponding to my data since the xml file is created by my application and I don t know the schema. This means I have to use a Map.class (or other container) right?

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you give more details in the question (what code/architecture you have at the moment, what you're aiming to achieve, etc) we're in a better position to advise you.

Comment: I edit my post, hoping it's easier to understand. thank again for your help