# XML to BSON using C#

Tags: c#, xml, mongodb, export, bson

I want to convert a XML file to BSON. then import the BSON to MongoDB. I searched but could not find how to covert this using C#. please provide me a source code to do this using C#

Comment: See the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611773/dynamic-xml-into-mongodb), also refer [XML to JSON in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037085/convert-xml-to-json-using-c-linq)

Comment: Deserialize your XML to a c# object. Then, serialize that object to a collection using the MongoDb drivers. Simplest is to add attributes to the C# class to control the serialization process. After you  tried that, if it doesn't work, post more specifics please so we can better help.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same Problem today. 
It's for sure not the best solution, but 
i solved it this way in my project and it works for what i need it:

1. Deserialize XML to Json
2. Deserialize Json to Bson

   ```
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
   {
     var body = reader.ReadToEnd(); // read input string

      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.LoadXml(body); // String to XML Document

      string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc); //XML to Json
      var bsdocument = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(jsonText); //Deserialize JSON String to BSon Document
      var mcollection = Program._database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test_collection_05");
      await mcollection.InsertOneAsync(bsdocument); //Insert into mongoDB
    }
   ```