# How to correctly serialize and deserialize xml in mongodb c#

Tags: c#, xml, mongodb

I have to store XML in mongodb in a project and I recently stumbled upon this solution:

[XML to BSON using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106827/xml-to-bson-using-c-sharp)

I've customized my own version like this:

```
    public void Insert_XML_Json_Bson(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        //object to json
        string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xml);

        //Deserialize JSON String to BSon Document
        var bsdocument = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(jsonText);

        //Fetch collection from mongo database
        var test_collection = Client.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test_collection");

        //Insert document into mongoDB
        test_collection.InsertOne(bsdocument);
    }
```

When I try to get the XML out of the bson I use this method:

```
    public void FetchXML()
    {
        //Fetch database collection
        var test_collection = Client.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test_collection");

        //Find all Bson Documents
        var documents = test_collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        foreach (var item in documents)
        {
            //Json to string to XML
            string bson_to_json = BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson(item);

            string v = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bson_to_json);


            xmlDoc.LoadXml(v);

            Console.WriteLine($"item is \n{xmlDoc.OuterXml}\n");
        }
    }
```

This method throws an exception:

[image]

Any idea why this happens and how can I fix it? Thanks for your time!

Edit2:As asked, the first line of the inserted document looks like this:

The XML is this:

```
<CATALOG>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>3</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Marsh Marigold</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Caltha palustris</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Sunny</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$6.81</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>051799</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Cowslip</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Caltha palustris</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$9.90</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Dutchman's-Breeches</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Dicentra cucullaria</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>3</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$6.44</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>012099</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Ginger, Wild</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Asarum canadense</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>3</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$9.03</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>041899</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Hepatica</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Hepatica americana</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$4.45</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>012699</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Liverleaf</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Hepatica americana</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$3.99</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>010299</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Jack-In-The-Pulpit</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Arisaema triphyllum</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$3.23</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>020199</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Mayapple</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Podophyllum peltatum</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>3</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$2.98</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>060599</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Phlox, Woodland</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Phlox divaricata</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>3</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Sun or Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$2.80</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>012299</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Phlox, Blue</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Phlox divaricata</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>3</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Sun or Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$5.59</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>021699</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Spring-Beauty</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Claytonia Virginica</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>7</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$6.59</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>020199</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Trillium</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Trillium grandiflorum</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>5</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Sun or Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$3.90</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>042999</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Wake Robin</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Trillium grandiflorum</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>5</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Sun or Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$3.20</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>022199</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Violet, Dog-Tooth</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Erythronium americanum</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$9.04</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>020199</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Trout Lily</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Erythronium americanum</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$6.94</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>032499</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Adder's-Tongue</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Erythronium americanum</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$9.58</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>041399</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Anemone</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Anemone blanda</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>6</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$8.86</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>122698</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Grecian Windflower</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Anemone blanda</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>6</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$9.16</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>071099</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Bee Balm</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Monarda didyma</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$4.59</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>050399</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Bergamot</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Monarda didyma</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$7.16</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>042799</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Black-Eyed Susan</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Rudbeckia hirta</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>Annual</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Sunny</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$9.80</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>061899</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Buttercup</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Ranunculus</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$2.57</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>061099</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Crowfoot</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Ranunculus</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$9.34</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>040399</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Butterfly Weed</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Asclepias tuberosa</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>Annual</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Sunny</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$2.78</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>063099</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Cinquefoil</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Potentilla</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>Annual</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$7.06</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>052599</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Primrose</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Oenothera</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>3 - 5</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Sunny</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$6.56</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>013099</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Gentian</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Gentiana</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Sun or Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$7.81</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>051899</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Blue Gentian</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Gentiana</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Sun or Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$8.56</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>050299</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Jacob's Ladder</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Polemonium caeruleum</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>Annual</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$9.26</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>022199</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Greek Valerian</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Polemonium caeruleum</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>Annual</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$4.36</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>071499</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>California Poppy</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Eschscholzia californica</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>Annual</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Sun</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$7.89</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>032799</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Shooting Star</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Dodecatheon</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>Annual</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$8.60</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>051399</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Snakeroot</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Cimicifuga</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>Annual</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$5.63</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>071199</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Cardinal Flower</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Lobelia cardinalis</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>2</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$3.02</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>022299</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
</CATALOG>
```

The v string printed (without lines) is this :

```
"\"{ \\\"_id\\\" : ObjectId(\\\"60794906c83b0c9efe0a43fd\\\"), \\\"CATALOG\\\" : { \\\"PLANT\\\" : [{ \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Bloodroot\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Sanguinaria canadensis\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$2.44\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"031599\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Columbine\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Aquilegia canadensis\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"3\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$9.37\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"030699\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Marsh Marigold\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Caltha palustris\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Sunny\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$6.81\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"051799\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Cowslip\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Caltha palustris\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$9.90\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"030699\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Dutchman's-Breeches\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Dicentra cucullaria\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"3\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$6.44\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"012099\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Ginger, Wild\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Asarum canadense\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"3\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$9.03\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"041899\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Hepatica\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Hepatica americana\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$4.45\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"012699\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Liverleaf\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Hepatica americana\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$3.99\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"010299\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Jack-In-The-Pulpit\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Arisaema triphyllum\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$3.23\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"020199\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Mayapple\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Podophyllum peltatum\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"3\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$2.98\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"060599\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Phlox, Woodland\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Phlox divaricata\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"3\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Sun or Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$2.80\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"012299\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Phlox, Blue\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Phlox divaricata\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"3\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Sun or Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$5.59\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"021699\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Spring-Beauty\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Claytonia Virginica\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"7\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$6.59\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"020199\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Trillium\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Trillium grandiflorum\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"5\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Sun or Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$3.90\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"042999\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Wake Robin\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Trillium grandiflorum\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"5\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Sun or Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$3.20\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"022199\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Violet, Dog-Tooth\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Erythronium americanum\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$9.04\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"020199\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Trout Lily\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Erythronium americanum\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$6.94\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"032499\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Adder's-Tongue\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Erythronium americanum\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$9.58\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"041399\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Anemone\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Anemone blanda\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"6\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$8.86\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"122698\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Grecian Windflower\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Anemone blanda\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"6\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$9.16\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"071099\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Bee Balm\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Monarda didyma\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$4.59\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"050399\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Bergamot\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Monarda didyma\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$7.16\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"042799\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Black-Eyed Susan\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Rudbeckia hirta\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"Annual\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Sunny\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$9.80\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"061899\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Buttercup\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Ranunculus\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$2.57\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"061099\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Crowfoot\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Ranunculus\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$9.34\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"040399\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Butterfly Weed\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Asclepias tuberosa\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"Annual\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Sunny\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$2.78\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"063099\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Cinquefoil\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Potentilla\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"Annual\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$7.06\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"052599\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Primrose\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Oenothera\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"3 - 5\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Sunny\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$6.56\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"013099\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Gentian\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Gentiana\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Sun or Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$7.81\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"051899\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Blue Gentian\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Gentiana\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"4\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Sun or Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$8.56\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"050299\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Jacob's Ladder\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Polemonium caeruleum\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"Annual\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$9.26\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"022199\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Greek Valerian\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Polemonium caeruleum\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"Annual\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$4.36\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"071499\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"California Poppy\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Eschscholzia californica\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"Annual\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Sun\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$7.89\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"032799\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Shooting Star\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Dodecatheon\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"Annual\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Mostly Shady\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$8.60\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"051399\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Snakeroot\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Cimicifuga\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"Annual\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$5.63\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"071199\\\" }, { \\\"COMMON\\\" : \\\"Cardinal Flower\\\", \\\"BOTANICAL\\\" : \\\"Lobelia cardinalis\\\", \\\"ZONE\\\" : \\\"2\\\", \\\"LIGHT\\\" : \\\"Shade\\\", \\\"PRICE\\\" : \\\"$3.02\\\", \\\"AVAILABILITY\\\" : \\\"022299\\\" }] } }\""
```

The inserted bson document is this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60794906c83b0c9efe0a43fd"
    },
    "CATALOG": {
        "PLANT": [{
            "COMMON": "Bloodroot",
            "BOTANICAL": "Sanguinaria canadensis",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$2.44",
            "AVAILABILITY": "031599"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Columbine",
            "BOTANICAL": "Aquilegia canadensis",
            "ZONE": "3",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$9.37",
            "AVAILABILITY": "030699"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Marsh Marigold",
            "BOTANICAL": "Caltha palustris",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Sunny",
            "PRICE": "$6.81",
            "AVAILABILITY": "051799"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Cowslip",
            "BOTANICAL": "Caltha palustris",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$9.90",
            "AVAILABILITY": "030699"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Dutchman's-Breeches",
            "BOTANICAL": "Dicentra cucullaria",
            "ZONE": "3",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$6.44",
            "AVAILABILITY": "012099"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Ginger, Wild",
            "BOTANICAL": "Asarum canadense",
            "ZONE": "3",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$9.03",
            "AVAILABILITY": "041899"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Hepatica",
            "BOTANICAL": "Hepatica americana",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$4.45",
            "AVAILABILITY": "012699"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Liverleaf",
            "BOTANICAL": "Hepatica americana",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$3.99",
            "AVAILABILITY": "010299"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Jack-In-The-Pulpit",
            "BOTANICAL": "Arisaema triphyllum",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$3.23",
            "AVAILABILITY": "020199"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Mayapple",
            "BOTANICAL": "Podophyllum peltatum",
            "ZONE": "3",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$2.98",
            "AVAILABILITY": "060599"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Phlox, Woodland",
            "BOTANICAL": "Phlox divaricata",
            "ZONE": "3",
            "LIGHT": "Sun or Shade",
            "PRICE": "$2.80",
            "AVAILABILITY": "012299"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Phlox, Blue",
            "BOTANICAL": "Phlox divaricata",
            "ZONE": "3",
            "LIGHT": "Sun or Shade",
            "PRICE": "$5.59",
            "AVAILABILITY": "021699"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Spring-Beauty",
            "BOTANICAL": "Claytonia Virginica",
            "ZONE": "7",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$6.59",
            "AVAILABILITY": "020199"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Trillium",
            "BOTANICAL": "Trillium grandiflorum",
            "ZONE": "5",
            "LIGHT": "Sun or Shade",
            "PRICE": "$3.90",
            "AVAILABILITY": "042999"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Wake Robin",
            "BOTANICAL": "Trillium grandiflorum",
            "ZONE": "5",
            "LIGHT": "Sun or Shade",
            "PRICE": "$3.20",
            "AVAILABILITY": "022199"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Violet, Dog-Tooth",
            "BOTANICAL": "Erythronium americanum",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$9.04",
            "AVAILABILITY": "020199"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Trout Lily",
            "BOTANICAL": "Erythronium americanum",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$6.94",
            "AVAILABILITY": "032499"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Adder's-Tongue",
            "BOTANICAL": "Erythronium americanum",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$9.58",
            "AVAILABILITY": "041399"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Anemone",
            "BOTANICAL": "Anemone blanda",
            "ZONE": "6",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$8.86",
            "AVAILABILITY": "122698"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Grecian Windflower",
            "BOTANICAL": "Anemone blanda",
            "ZONE": "6",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$9.16",
            "AVAILABILITY": "071099"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Bee Balm",
            "BOTANICAL": "Monarda didyma",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$4.59",
            "AVAILABILITY": "050399"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Bergamot",
            "BOTANICAL": "Monarda didyma",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$7.16",
            "AVAILABILITY": "042799"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Black-Eyed Susan",
            "BOTANICAL": "Rudbeckia hirta",
            "ZONE": "Annual",
            "LIGHT": "Sunny",
            "PRICE": "$9.80",
            "AVAILABILITY": "061899"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Buttercup",
            "BOTANICAL": "Ranunculus",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$2.57",
            "AVAILABILITY": "061099"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Crowfoot",
            "BOTANICAL": "Ranunculus",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$9.34",
            "AVAILABILITY": "040399"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Butterfly Weed",
            "BOTANICAL": "Asclepias tuberosa",
            "ZONE": "Annual",
            "LIGHT": "Sunny",
            "PRICE": "$2.78",
            "AVAILABILITY": "063099"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Cinquefoil",
            "BOTANICAL": "Potentilla",
            "ZONE": "Annual",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$7.06",
            "AVAILABILITY": "052599"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Primrose",
            "BOTANICAL": "Oenothera",
            "ZONE": "3 - 5",
            "LIGHT": "Sunny",
            "PRICE": "$6.56",
            "AVAILABILITY": "013099"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Gentian",
            "BOTANICAL": "Gentiana",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Sun or Shade",
            "PRICE": "$7.81",
            "AVAILABILITY": "051899"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Blue Gentian",
            "BOTANICAL": "Gentiana",
            "ZONE": "4",
            "LIGHT": "Sun or Shade",
            "PRICE": "$8.56",
            "AVAILABILITY": "050299"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Jacob's Ladder",
            "BOTANICAL": "Polemonium caeruleum",
            "ZONE": "Annual",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$9.26",
            "AVAILABILITY": "022199"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Greek Valerian",
            "BOTANICAL": "Polemonium caeruleum",
            "ZONE": "Annual",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$4.36",
            "AVAILABILITY": "071499"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "California Poppy",
            "BOTANICAL": "Eschscholzia californica",
            "ZONE": "Annual",
            "LIGHT": "Sun",
            "PRICE": "$7.89",
            "AVAILABILITY": "032799"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Shooting Star",
            "BOTANICAL": "Dodecatheon",
            "ZONE": "Annual",
            "LIGHT": "Mostly Shady",
            "PRICE": "$8.60",
            "AVAILABILITY": "051399"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Snakeroot",
            "BOTANICAL": "Cimicifuga",
            "ZONE": "Annual",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$5.63",
            "AVAILABILITY": "071199"
        }, {
            "COMMON": "Cardinal Flower",
            "BOTANICAL": "Lobelia cardinalis",
            "ZONE": "2",
            "LIGHT": "Shade",
            "PRICE": "$3.02",
            "AVAILABILITY": "022299"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe provide the first line of the inserted document. Maybe there are other documents in this collection which are not serialized XML. Have a look with mongoshell.

Comment: Added the first few lines of the inserted document as picture. Please take a look. @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: And what is the according XML? What are the first lines of `v`? Do you expect us being clairvoyant? And please don't paste screenshots, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: I've updated the question. The v string is one line though. @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I think the problem is the id which cannot be parsed into the XML file. I should filter it out somehow from the result.

Comment: Just for curiosity: How does it serialize XML attributes, comments or processing instructions? Or XML namespaces (the use of $ and . in field names is not recommended and is not supported by the official MongoDB drivers). How does it preserve the order of elements? (BSON attributes are not ordered). I would prefer to store the entire XML as plain text.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It simply gets an XML and serializes it. It doesn't check anything at all because I'm using legacy code. I think I should try and save it as string as you suggest to avoid potential issues.