# toJSONObject() in Java doesnt differentiate list of objects and object. Is this a result of the information loss during the conversion?

Tags: xml, json

I am trying to convert a xml to json string using the below function

**JSONObject org.json.XML.toJSONObject(String xmlstring)**

The issue is this function cant differentiate between a collection list and a object. For eg say

I convert the following

*Case1*

**xml:**

```
<Book>  
    <Topic>1</Topic> 
</Book>
```

**json:**

```
{
  "Book": {
    "Topic": "1"
  }
}
```

*Case2*

**xml:**

```
<Book>  
    <Topic>1</Topic> 
    <Topic>2</Topic> 
</Book>
```

**Json:**

```
{
  "Book": {
    "Topic": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  }
}
```

The xml format in both cases are the same but the json results aren't the same. If you notice in case1 the Topic equals an object whereas in case2 Topic equals a array of objects.

The function declaration clearly says
**Some information may be lost in this transformation because JSON is a data format and XML is a document format.**

Is this a result of the data loss from xml to json? 
How can I get the result in case1 as

```
{
  "Book": {
    "Topic": [
      "1"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You might find [this answer helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15015482/227884)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickest way to convert XML to JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java)

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If yes please post an answer.