# Java convert XML to JSON and determine if array or object

Tags: java, xml, json

I need to convert XML into JSON and I have the following code which works fine. The problem, however, arises when an XML element should actually be converted into an array. My question is in two parts:

1) What is the proper way to represent an array in xml?

Here is the xml I'm currently using. The contents of elements should actually be an array. So elements[0] should be the element within.

```
<project id="200">
    <name>test</name>
    <elements>
        <element>
            <id>body</id>
            <width>200</width>
            <height>400</height>
            <children/>
        </element>
    </elements>
</project>
```

2) How can I convert the xml into JSON containing JSON arrays as well as objects?

```
private String xmlToJson(String xml) throws IOException {

    JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml);

    return jsonObject.toString(4);

} // End of XML to JSON
```

Many thanks

Comment: Please go through the previous answers on SO

 http://stackoverflow.com/a/1823328/1759128

Comment: unfortunately that solution doesn't answer my question as it doesn't single out arrays

Comment: Your best bet is to use an XML tool to create the array as a List, then a JSON tool to convert the List to JSON.

Comment: @HotLicks, this qwuestion is - "how to do this"

Comment: @msangel - How to do what?  There are multiple tools for both -- just lash two of them together.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library with static method `U.xmlToJson(xml)`. It supports a special attribute array="true" which forces the element to be an array.

```
<project id="200">
    <name>test</name>
    <elements>
        <element array="true">
            <id>body</id>
            <width>200</width>
            <height>400</height>
            <children/>
        </element>
    </elements>
</project>
```

Output:

```
{
  "project": {
    "-id": "200",
    "name": "test",
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": "body",
        "width": "200",
        "height": "400",
        "children": {
          "-self-closing": "true"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```

Comment: I know we have MODE to replace self-closing portion value as null, do we have any MODE to replace with EMPTY

Comment: I can add a new mode REPLACE_SELF_CLOSING_WITH_EMPTY.

Comment: It will be available in nearest release.

Comment: Is there a config/a way to discard "#omit-xml-declaration" key from response?

Comment: We may exclude keys with help of method U.remove(map, key). As alternative you may add xml header.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your 1st question: `What is the proper way to represent an array in xml?`

Please refere to: http://www.w3.org/2005/07/xml-schema-patterns.html#Vector