# Convert xml to json with Java

Tags: java, xml, json

Is there a way to convert a xml file to json? The XML can be of any structure, therefore there is no POJO class for instantiation. I need to convert the xml to json or to a Map, without root nodes.

For example:

```
<import name="person">
    <item>
        <firstName>Emil</firstName>
        <lastName>Example</lastName>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <street>Example Blvd.</street>
            </address>
            <address>
                <street>Example Ave.</street>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </item>
</import>
```

Expected JSON

```
{
    "firstName": "Emil",
    "lastName": "Example",
    "addresses": [
        { "street" : "Example Blvd." },
        { "street" : "Example Ave." }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of SAX or DOM parsers? It should be fairly easy using basic XML parsing.

Comment: There is no canocical mapping from XML to JSON. What about attributes or namespaces? What about elements containing both text and other elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickest way to convert XML to JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java)

Comment: @Dominic - Is there any way if we can remove root element and can we do vice-versa?

Answer (score 17):

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

XML.toJSONObject(xml_text).toString()
```

[org.json.XML](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/XML.html)

Comment: If anyone wonders how to get this library jar, here you go: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/

Comment: @All- Could you please guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450130/convert-json-to-xml-and-vice-versa?noredirect=1#comment105082819_59450130

Answer (score 8):

You can Use JSON and XML Library from [json.org](http://www.json.org/java/)

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import org.junit.Test;

public class XmlToJsonTest {
    private static final String XML_TEXT = "<note>\n" +
            "<to>Tove</to>\n" +
            "<from>Jani</from>\n" +
            "<heading>Reminder</heading>\n" +
            "<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\n" +
            "</note>";
    private static final int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;

    @Test
    public void convert() {
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(XML_TEXT);
        String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
        System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
    }
}
```

Source

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Output

```
{"note": {
    "heading": "Reminder",
    "from": "Jani",
    "to": "Tove",
    "body": "Don't forget me this weekend!"
}}
```

Comment: This is not what i want ("without root nodes").

Comment: Just remove first and last symbols )

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Java 8**, you should check out my open source library: [unXml](https://github.com/tajakobsen/unxml). unXml basically maps from Xpaths to Json-attributes.

It's available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cunxml).

*Example*

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.factory.ParsingFactory;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.parsers.Parser;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class ParserExample {
    public ObjectNode parseXml(String xml){
        Parsing parsing = ParsingFactory.getInstance().create();
        Document document = parsing.xml().document(xml);

        Parser<ObjectNode> parser = parsing.obj("//item")
            .attribute("firstName", "firstName")
            .attribute("lastName", "lastName")
            .attribute("addresses", parsing.arr("addresses/address", parsing.obj()
                .attribute("street", "street")
            ))
            .build();

        ObjectNode result = parser.apply(document);
        return result;
    }
}
```

It will return a [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) `ObjectNode`, with the json from your example.

Answer (score 2):

On this [website](http://www.json.org/) you find some helpful classes for your task (in the java section at the bottom of the page).

```
public class Main {

    public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
    public static String TEST_XML_STRING = "Your xml string here";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
            String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
            System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            System.out.println(je.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the link is down

Comment: Yeah, the links is down, but http://www.json.org/ contains a "Java" section with all the available open source libraries to deal with JSON. I used this library: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/

Answer (score 2):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library has static method `U.xmlToJson(xml)`. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/tIH)

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<root>\n"
            + "  <FirstItem>1</FirstItem>\n  <SecondItem>2</SecondItem>\n</root>";
        System.out.println(U.xmlToJson(xml));
    }
}

// {
//  "FirstItem": "1",
//  "SecondItem": "2"
// }
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove XML root tags and simply create json? And vice versa?

Comment: You may convert xml to map, edit map and then generate json.

Comment: Could you please share source code sample example ?

Answer (score 1):

I am used [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) but I found more Efficient Library to Convert **`XML`** to **`Json`** is **[XmlToJson](https://github.com/fakefacebook/XmlToJson)**

Which is Given Best Customization to making `Json` from`XML`

Add the `libary` dependency to your APP `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.smart-fun:XmlToJson:1.4.4'    // add this line
}
```

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <library>
    <book id="007">James Bond</book>
    <book id="000">Book for the dummies</book>
    </library>
```

- ## Custom Content names

  ```
  public String convertXmlToJson(String xml) {
  XmlToJson xmlToJson = new XmlToJson.Builder(xml)
      .setContentName("/library/book", "title")
      .build();
  return xmlToJson.toString();
  }
  ```

  ---

  ```
  "library":{  
    "book":[  
       {  
          "id":"007",
          "title":"James Bond"
       },
       {  
          "id":"000",
          "title":"Book for the dummies"
       }
     ]
    }
   }
  ```

---

- ## Custom Attributes names

  ```
  public String convertXmlToJson(String xml) {
    XmlToJson xmlToJson = new XmlToJson.Builder(xml)
      .setAttributeName("/library/book/id", "code")
      .build();
    return xmlToJson.toString();
  }
  ```

  ---

  ```
  {  
    "library":{  
    "book":[  
       {  
          "code":"007",
          "content":"James Bond"
       },
       {  
          "code":"000",
          "content":"Book for the dummies"
       }
    ]
   }
  }
  ```

**and Much More Efficient Techniques to Customize your Json**

**[Click here to Check out on Github](https://github.com/fakefacebook/XmlToJson#xml-to-json-for-android)**

Answer (score 1):

**You can use standard tools for it**

1. Use the tool `xjc` from your jdk to [generate Java classes from schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463231/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-xsd)

   > Since `Java 9` you must use explicitly add JAXB as module with `–add-modules java.se.ee` 
   >   See: [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

Since Java 11 you have to download `xjc` in an extra step from https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/

2. Read in as `XML` write out as `JSON` using [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.8.1)

**Example**

With https://schema.datacite.org/meta/kernel-4.1/metadata.xsd

**1. Use the tool `xjc` from your jdk**

In my example I will use a fairly complex example based on datacite schemas.

```
/path/to/jdk/bin/xjc -d /path/to/java/project \
-p stack24174963.datacite \
 https://schema.datacite.org/meta/kernel-4.1/metadata.xsd
```

This will reply with

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
stack24174963/datacite/Box.java
stack24174963/datacite/ContributorType.java
stack24174963/datacite/DateType.java
stack24174963/datacite/DescriptionType.java
stack24174963/datacite/FunderIdentifierType.java
stack24174963/datacite/NameType.java
stack24174963/datacite/ObjectFactory.java
stack24174963/datacite/Point.java
stack24174963/datacite/RelatedIdentifierType.java
stack24174963/datacite/RelationType.java
stack24174963/datacite/Resource.java
stack24174963/datacite/ResourceType.java
stack24174963/datacite/TitleType.java
stack24174963/datacite/package-info.java
```

**2. Read in as `XML` write out as `JSON` using Jackson**

```
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

  import stack24174963.datacite.Resource;

  public class HowToXmlToJsonWithSchema {
    @Test
    public void readXmlAndConvertToSchema() throws Exception {
        String example = "schemas/datacite/kernel-4.1/example/datacite-example-complicated-v4.1.xml";
        try (InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(example)) {
            Resource resource = JAXB.unmarshal(in, Resource.class);
            System.out.println(asJson(resource));
        }
    }

    private String asJson(Object obj) throws Exception {
        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
        new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true).writeValue(w, obj);
        String result = w.toString();
        return result;
    }
  }
```

Prints:

```
 {
      "identifier" : {
        "value" : "10.5072/testpub",
        "identifierType" : "DOI"
      },
      "creators" : {
        "creator" : [ {
          "creatorName" : {
            "value" : "Smith, John",
            "nameType" : "PERSONAL"
          },
          "givenName" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<givenName xmlns=\"http://datacite.org/schema/kernel-4\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">John</givenName>",
          "familyName" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<familyName xmlns=\"http://datacite.org/schema/kernel-4\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">Smith</familyName>",
          "nameIdentifier" : [ ],
          "affiliation" : [ ]
        }, {
          "creatorName" : {
            "value" : "つまらないものですが",
            "nameType" : null
          },
          "givenName" : null,
          "familyName" : null,
          "nameIdentifier" : [ {
            "value" : "0000000134596520",
            "nameIdentifierScheme" : "ISNI",
            "schemeURI" : "http://isni.org/isni/"
          } ],
          "affiliation" : [ ]
        } ]
      },
      "titles" : {
        "title" : [ {
          "value" : "Właściwości rzutowań podprzestrzeniowych",
          "titleType" : null,
          "lang" : "pl"
        }, {
          "value" : "Translation of Polish titles",
          "titleType" : "TRANSLATED_TITLE",
          "lang" : "en"
        } ]
      },
      "publisher" : "Springer",
      "publicationYear" : "2010",
      "resourceType" : {
        "value" : "Monograph",
        "resourceTypeGeneral" : "TEXT"
      },
      "subjects" : {
        "subject" : [ {
          "value" : "830 German & related literatures",
          "subjectScheme" : "DDC",
          "schemeURI" : null,
          "valueURI" : null,
          "lang" : "en"
        }, {
          "value" : "Polish Literature",
          "subjectScheme" : null,
          "schemeURI" : null,
          "valueURI" : null,
          "lang" : "en"
        } ]
      },
      "contributors" : {
        "contributor" : [ {
          "contributorName" : {
            "value" : "Doe, John",
            "nameType" : "PERSONAL"
          },
          "givenName" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<givenName xmlns=\"http://datacite.org/schema/kernel-4\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">John</givenName>",
          "familyName" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<familyName xmlns=\"http://datacite.org/schema/kernel-4\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">Doe</familyName>",
          "nameIdentifier" : [ {
            "value" : "0000-0001-5393-1421",
            "nameIdentifierScheme" : "ORCID",
            "schemeURI" : "http://orcid.org/"
          } ],
          "affiliation" : [ ],
          "contributorType" : "DATA_COLLECTOR"
        } ]
      },
      "dates" : null,
      "language" : "de",
      "alternateIdentifiers" : {
        "alternateIdentifier" : [ {
          "value" : "937-0-4523-12357-6",
          "alternateIdentifierType" : "ISBN"
        } ]
      },
      "relatedIdentifiers" : {
        "relatedIdentifier" : [ {
          "value" : "10.5272/oldertestpub",
          "resourceTypeGeneral" : null,
          "relatedIdentifierType" : "DOI",
          "relationType" : "IS_PART_OF",
          "relatedMetadataScheme" : null,
          "schemeURI" : null,
          "schemeType" : null
        } ]
      },
      "sizes" : {
        "size" : [ "256 pages" ]
      },
      "formats" : {
        "format" : [ "pdf" ]
      },
      "version" : "2",
      "rightsList" : {
        "rights" : [ {
          "value" : "Creative Commons Attribution-NoDerivs 2.0 Generic",
          "rightsURI" : "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/",
          "lang" : null
        } ]
      },
      "descriptions" : {
        "description" : [ {
          "content" : [ "\n      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea\n      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores\n      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n    " ],
          "descriptionType" : "ABSTRACT",
          "lang" : "la"
        } ]
      },
      "geoLocations" : null,
      "fundingReferences" : null
    }
```

For example input XML :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <resource xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://datacite.org/schema/kernel-4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://datacite.org/schema/kernel-4 http://schema.datacite.org/meta/kernel-4.1/metadata.xsd">
    <identifier identifierType="DOI">10.5072/testpub</identifier>
    <creators>
      <creator>
        <creatorName nameType="Personal">Smith, John</creatorName>
        <givenName>John</givenName>
        <familyName>Smith</familyName>
      </creator>
      <creator>
        <creatorName>つまらないものですが</creatorName>
        <nameIdentifier nameIdentifierScheme="ISNI" schemeURI="http://isni.org/isni/">0000000134596520</nameIdentifier>
      </creator>
    </creators>
    <titles>
      <title xml:lang="pl">Właściwości rzutowań podprzestrzeniowych</title>
      <title xml:lang="en" titleType="TranslatedTitle">Translation of Polish titles</title>
    </titles>
    <publisher>Springer</publisher>
    <publicationYear>2010</publicationYear>
    <subjects>
      <subject xml:lang="en" subjectScheme="DDC">830 German &amp; related literatures</subject>
      <subject xml:lang="en">Polish Literature</subject>
    </subjects>
    <contributors>
      <contributor contributorType="DataCollector">
        <contributorName nameType="Personal">Doe, John</contributorName>
        <givenName>John</givenName>
        <familyName>Doe</familyName>
        <nameIdentifier nameIdentifierScheme="ORCID" schemeURI="http://orcid.org/">0000-0001-5393-1421</nameIdentifier>
      </contributor>
    </contributors>
    <language>de</language>
    <resourceType resourceTypeGeneral="Text">Monograph</resourceType>
    <alternateIdentifiers>
      <alternateIdentifier alternateIdentifierType="ISBN">937-0-4523-12357-6</alternateIdentifier>
    </alternateIdentifiers>
    <relatedIdentifiers>
      <relatedIdentifier relatedIdentifierType="DOI" relationType="IsPartOf">10.5272/oldertestpub</relatedIdentifier>
    </relatedIdentifiers>
    <sizes>
      <size>256 pages</size>
    </sizes>
    <formats>
      <format>pdf</format>
    </formats>
    <version>2</version>
    <rightsList>
      <rights rightsURI="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-NoDerivs 2.0 Generic</rights>
    </rightsList>
    <descriptions>
      <description xml:lang="la" descriptionType="Abstract">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
        et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </description>
    </descriptions>
  </resource>
```