# Json to XML to Json with respect to XML Schema

Tags: java, json, xml, xsd, schema

Edit:
My question is similar to the below question:
[Converting XML to JSON using XML Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174963/converting-xml-to-json-using-xml-schema?rq=1)

But:

1. With Java and not Javascript
2. In both directions (`XML->JSON` and `JSON->XML`)
3. A general Java library, not related to Node.js
4. Do it on-the-fly

Something like `String json = convertToJSON(xml, xmlSchema)`and `String xml = convertToXML(json, xmlSchema)`

Comment: Personally me, I don't understand what do you mean by "conversion of XML to JSON with respect to XML Schema".

Comment: Why do you want to convert XML to JSON? I do not understand what you mean. Why don't you make your Rest services produce JSON?

Comment: The previous commenter is right, it would be better to use proper JSON libraries to produce JSON as an _alternative_ to XML directly from the data, not convert XML to JSON.

Comment: Rephrased my question.

Answer (score 1):

The [sax2j](https://github.com/kswmsw/sax2j) (schema-aware XML-to-JSON translator) library/tool seems to do the trick. It's only half of the answer since only for the XML->JSON translation, as far as I can see, but it's a start.

Comment: I need the convertor to be XSD aware so that the conversion respect the definitions in the schema, just like in the question linked to

Comment: I've looked at that library and emailed the author and you are right. The main issues with the library is that is made for a one-off conversion (not on the fly) and its only for XML->JSON and not the other way around. I'll continue studying it.

Comment: Is there version for .NET that does XML -> JSON based on XSD?