# issue converting xml to json in android

Tags: android, json, jackson

using XML.toJSONObject(xml)

```
<root>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</root>
```

and result is

```
{"root":{"dependencies":[{"dependency":[{"groupId":"com.fasterxml.jackson.core","artifactId":"jackson-annotations","version":"LATEST"},{"groupId":"com.fasterxml.jackson.core","artifactId":"jackson-core","version":"LATEST"},{"groupId":"com.fasterxml.jackson.core","artifactId":"jackson-databind","version":"LATEST"}]},{"dependency":{"groupId":"com.fasterxml.jackson.core","artifactId":"jackson-annotations","version":"LATEST"}}]}}
```

at dependencies[0] dependency will converted in array i.e. [OK]

but at dependencies[1] dependency will converted in object i.e. create problem to parse with jackson in pojo class.

Comment: it seems the given xml is not valid one because at last <root> is specified while should b </root>

Comment: do you need java Beans classes for this?

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay m parsing it using json jackson, but that gives error

Comment: can you post the logs?? everything seems correct, nothing looks wrong!!

Comment: have u understand my problem? in my pojo class i have taken "dependency" as array list , then how dependency{} will parse as array

Comment: yes i do!! actually yours json output string is coming wrong, i checked at http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.VB_GUvmSw8Y and converted yours xml to json which is different!!

Comment: at dependencies[1] , dependency should be dependency[{"groupId":"com.fasterxml.jackson.core","artifactId":"jackson-annotations","version":"LATEST"}]

Comment: please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61652/discussion-between-rohit-and-jitesh-upadhyay).