# Json conversion from XML with single / multiple children

Tags: java, json, xml, gson, org.json

I'm using org.json library to convert XML into JSON:

```
JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xmlData);
```

I get the XML as API response. The XML (xmlData) looks like below:

```
<StudentsTable>
  <Student name = "a" surname = "b" age = "15" />
  <Student name = "x" surname = "y" age = "14" />
</StudentsTable>
```

When the above XML converted to JSON, the children 'Student' is resolved as List. This is as expected.

However, sometimes my XML can have only one child. Example:

```
<StudentsTable>
  <Student name = "a" surname = "b" age = "15" />
</StudentsTable>
```

In this case, since its only one child, it is converted to the object 'Student' instead of the List. Therefore, my JSON parsing (using gson), which expects it to be List, fails in this case.

I need an advice on how to handle this case. I want the children to be resolved as List even if its single child!

I am open to using any other library for XML to JSON conversion if that can handle this better.

Comment: Duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/q/35656738/4481302.

Answer: JSONArray for single XML element XML here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61816190/4481302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your purpose after getting the XML?

From the GitHub page of this project (and your specific method):
[Click here to read](https://github.com/ning/org-json/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/XML.java)

```
Sequences of similar elements are represented as JSONArrays
```

Maybe you can create by your own the `JSONObject`. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String singleStudentXmlData = "<StudentsTable>\n" +
            "  <Student name = \"a\" surname = \"b\" age = \"15\" />\n" +
            "</StudentsTable>";

    JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(singleStudentXmlData);
    try {
        JSONObject students = new JSONObject().put("Students", new JSONArray().put(jsonObject.getJSONObject("StudentsTable").getJSONObject("Student")));
        jsonObject.put("StudentsTable", students);
    } catch (JSONException e){
        // You can continue with your program, this is multi student case (works for your by default library behavior)
    }

    simpleTest(jsonObject);
}

private static void simpleTest(JSONObject modifiedJSONObject){

    String multiStudentXmlData = "<StudentsTable>\n" +
            "  <Student name = \"a\" surname = \"b\" age = \"15\" />\n" +
            "  <Student name = \"a\" surname = \"b\" age = \"15\" />\n" +
            "</StudentsTable>";

    JSONObject multiStudentJSONObject = XML.toJSONObject(multiStudentXmlData);

    assert(modifiedJSONObject == multiStudentJSONObject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can do that but then I'll have to know if there is only one child in the response. So basically, I'll have to kind of parse XML before conversion! I'm looking for an easy way to do this instead of parsing and checking the number of children!

Comment: That's the reason I've added the try-catch stuff there. An exception will be thrown if there is more than one student. In case of one student, the code will run without exception. You catch both of cases here, no?