# Adding <?xml-multiple?> in select statement

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I select data from an Oracle SQL database using XMLELEMENTs. These data get passed to an application that will convert it into JSON and then sends it to a REST API.

Currently, I have the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656738/how-to-convert-single-child-xml-element-to-json-array), and the solution should be to add `<?xml-multiple?>` as a tag.

How can I select it from the database?

```
SELECT XMLEMENT("Body", 
XMLELEMENT("User", 
XMLELEMENT("Name", UserName), 
XMLELEMENT("Adress", Adress))) 
FROM USERS;
```

Let's say I want to mark that there could be multiple users with xml-multiple.
How do I need to change my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the [XMLPI](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb13gen.htm#GUID-43A6EF19-9A0D-4AA8-B73E-21A46BFFA81C) function. It allows you to add processing instructions to the XML.

```
SELECT XMLEMENT("Body", 
XMLPI("xml-multiple"),
XMLELEMENT("User", 
XMLELEMENT("Name", UserName), 
XMLELEMENT("Adress", Adress))) 
FROM USERS;
```