# Smack receiving messages in XML format can i change them to JSON?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I am developing an android chatting app with the use of `Openfire` as a support server for XMPP and smack library as a android implementation of XMPP.

Things are going well. Till i find this received message from another user. The format is like this :

```
<message to="rajesh2@peacock-hp" id="0mpqe-10" type="chat" from="rajesh1@peacock-hp/Smack">
   <body>{"Date":"8 Jul 2016","Time":"0:40p.m.","body":" vhklv","isMine":true,"msgid":"909-08","receiver":"rajesh2","sender":"rajesh1","senderName":"rajesh1"}</body>
   <thread>06ed73bb-21ad-4276-80cb-0ea4fc9d9dfb</thread>
</message>
```

My listener  which is receiving messages :

```
private class MMessageListener implements ChatMessageListener {

    public MMessageListener(Context contxt) {
    }

    @Override
    public void processMessage(final org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat chat,
                               final Message message) {
        Log.i("MyXMPP_MESSAGE_LISTENER", "Xmpp message received: '"
                + message);

    }

}
```

**My Question is :** Can i receive this message in JSON format instead of
 XML ??

As I am learning smack and xmpp please guide me if i am wrong at some places. correct me if any one of you find me wrong.

Comment: The server side developer should make it in JSON format , You can't do it from your android app

Comment: There is no server side development @ZahidulIslam. We just have a database in xampp and Openfire  provides everything..!!

Comment: Do you really want to receive the message in JSON? Or do you just want to extract the JSON within the `<body/>` element (`'"Date":"8 Jul 2016","Time":"0:40p.m.","body":" vhklv",...'`) of the message stanza?

Comment: I want to receive JSON..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya can you please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627599/how-to-configure-push-mode-configuration-in-xmpp-with-fcm-refresh-token-using-sm

Comment: @jankigadhiya http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630978/how-to-use-smack-4-1-for-how-to-send-info-query-packet-to-xmpp-server help me if possible

Answer (score 1):

You can convert messages to JSON format through [a project](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) on Github.

Example :

```
public class Main {

  public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
  public static String TEST_XML_STRING =
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><test attrib=\"moretest\">Turn this to JSON</test>";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
        String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
        System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        System.out.println(je.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
{
  "test": {
     "attrib": "moretest",
     "content": "Turn this to JSON"
   }
}
```

Credit goes to [Quickest way to convert XML to JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java)

Comment: Actually this is not what I am looking for i don't want to convert XML to JSON but i need my openfire to respond with JSON directly. I will give this a try if it is not possible directly. Thank you for the effort..!!

Comment: Sorry... But I've already mention the link of original post and I've just pick up the example only.

Comment: @Khan can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627599/how-to-configure-push-mode-configuration-in-xmpp-with-fcm-refresh-token-using-sm

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ I've seen your question but seriously I've no idea how smack works.

Answer (score 1):

Json it's not the reply format for Openfire.
Of course, you can rewrite all Openfire to "talk" in Json, but to me has no sense.

What I suggest to you:

- if you have a performance issue, you can look **maybe** for Ejabber
- If you need a Json, **maybe** Prosody IM has a plugin
- If you don't  want to broke your head with XmlPullParser, give a try 
  to    [Bubbler](http://babbler-xmpp.blogspot.it/) in alternative to Smack.
- If you just don't feel confident with XML, just implement a "toJson"    for each Stanza type so you'll have something like
  (thanking @Khan)

---

```
MyMessage extends Message

public String toJson()
{
JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(this.toXML());
        String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
}
```

and you'll be able to use a Json.

Comment: i haven't written openfire. I have just installed it on my PC. Can please give me something (some setting kind of thing) which will set my openfire to talk in JSON. If that is impossible then i will switch to your alternatives. Thank you..!!

Comment: it's impossible without a massive rewrite of Openfire to talk in Json, but as I suggested, if the problem it's just to have Json on client, just extend custom Stanzas (message, Iq and presence) to write a Json and use it.