# How to convert a complex XML to JSON in java?

Tags: java, json, xml

I have an XML where the structure looks as below. It is a complex XML where we have multiple attributes. How to convert this XML to JSON using java. Please suggest.

The input looks something like below.

input

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="UTE-8"?>
        <Products>
            <Product>
                <List>
                    <Property name="description" value="Skype"/>
                </List>
            </Product>
        </Products>
```

Expected Output is

```
 {
       "Products": {
          "Product": {
             List": [
                {
                   "description": "Skype"
                }
             ]
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: you can find some ways [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java)

Comment: JSON and XML Library from json.org

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with the JSON Api with something like below

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import org.junit.Test;
```

And then in the code use below way:

```
JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(XML_TEXT);
        String jsonString = xmlJSONObj.toString();
        System.out.println(jsonString );
```

Comment: Hi, Tried your code. Getting the following output. {
           "Products": {
              "Product": {
                 List": [
                    {
                       "name": "description",
                       "value": "Skype"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        }