# XML - XPath DOM parser in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<docs>
<doc>
    <person>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <description>
            <age>23</age>
            <alias>M C</alias>
        </description>
        <description>
            <age>24</age>
            <alias>John</alias>
        </description>
    </person>
<doc>
<doc>
    <person>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <description>
            <age>24</age>
            <alias>Steve</alias>
        </description>
    </person>
<doc>
</docs>
```

I do not have control over the xml. All I get is such xml documents and xpath for the elements. I have write a java program to read the data and convert it to Json object. I am using xPath and dom parser and since we get the xPath for xml, I thought I will make use of it as the xPath may change in the future. So I had xPath for all the elements in the property file, so if there is a change I will have minimum changes in the program. And unfortunately the program should be case insensitive, so I used translate(xPath) to handle it. I have following class

```
public class Person {
  private List<String> name;
  private List<String> age;
  private List<String> alias;
  //getter and setter
}
```

The issue is having multiple doc nodes and each can have multiple age and alias elements. Earlier it was not the requirement so I used XPath to get the text but now I can't use it because the xPath of //person/description will return 3 nodes, 2 from first doc and one from another doc. The issue is I need to differentiate the description tag to say whether it is coming from first doc or the other one. So the final Json will look like

```
{
  "docs":
  {
    "doc":
    [
      {
        "description":
         [
           {
             "age": 23,
             "alias": "M C"
           },
           {
             "age": 24,
             "alias": "John"
           }
         ]
       },
       {
          "description":
           [
            {
              "age": 24,
              "alias": "Steve"
            }
           ]
         }
    ]
  }
 }
```

So all I could think of is compile the xPath expression - //docs/doc, I will have 2 nodes at this point and get the child nodes and loop through by getting the child nodes and do something like if

```
element.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("age")
```

then add to age list and then do like list of lists , so I will end up having

```
docs[[[23, "M C"],[24, "John"]],[[24, "Steve"]]]
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: Are you required to use XPath or are answers using other tools or techniques acceptable?

Comment: No I just used xpath because the client gives us XML with xpath so if they change it , it will be easy to maintain.. I just don't want to try different parser like saxparser

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to XPath is the [Java JSON library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180130). This library has features for both consuming XML and producing JSON. To complete this transform, use the following:

```
public class Main {

    private static int SPACES_PER_INDENT = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            // Citation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java
            URI file = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("docs.xml").toURI();
            String xmlContents = readFromInputStream(file);
            JSONObject jsonContents = XML.toJSONObject(xmlContents);
            String jsonString = jsonContents.toString(SPACES_PER_INDENT);
            System.out.println(jsonString);
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String readFromInputStream(URI uri) throws IOException {
        // Citation: http://www.baeldung.com/reading-file-in-java
        Path path = Paths.get(uri);
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
        lines.forEach(line -> data.append(line).append("\n"));
        lines.close();

        return data.toString();
    }
}
```

The contents of `docs.xml`, which is present on the classpath, is as follows (note that I changed the `<doc>...<doc>` tags in the question to `<doc>...</doc>`):

```
<docs>
    <doc>
        <person>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <description>
                <age>23</age>
                <alias>M C</alias>
            </description>
            <description>
                <age>24</age>
                <alias>John</alias>
            </description>
        </person>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <person>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <description>
                <age>24</age>
                <alias>Steve</alias>
            </description>
        </person>
    </doc>
</docs>
```

The `pom.xml` for this project is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow.albanoj2</groupId>
    <artifactId>XmlToJson</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The resulting output is:

```
{"docs": {"doc": [
    {"person": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "description": [
            {
                "alias": "M C",
                "age": 23
            },
            {
                "alias": "John",
                "age": 24
            }
        ]
    }},
    {"person": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "description": {
            "alias": "Steve",
            "age": 24
        }
    }}
]}}
```

If it's easier to read, the source code for this solution is contained in the following repository: https://github.com/albanoj2/XmlToJsonDocTranslation. Note that the bulk of this answer is derived from [Quickest way to convert XML to JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java), but has been tailored to suit the specific needs of this question (such as reading the XML from a file).

Comment: I saw this when I started but I don't remember why I didn't go with it. One other requirement is I need to add some other custom extra entities to json that's not there in XML. I'm sure there should be a way in the json library.

Comment: You can manipulate the `JSONObject` that is returned when you convert the XML to JSON (i.e. `JSONObject jsonContents = XML.toJSONObject(xmlContents)`). You can add new keys, lists, etc. to that `JSONObject`. For more information, see: https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html.

Comment: I think i remember why I did not go with this one. We rename the tag names when converted to Json because some of the tag names in xml is not properly named/structrured. For example

Comment: Sorry to have in 2 separate comments. I will look into it but I dont think I can rename the tags like if it is <name> tag, the key in Json will be PersonName.

Comment: You can do a conversion to accomplish that. I.e. create a function that takes in a JSONObject and return another JSONObject with he renamed tags.