# Parsing Aadhaar XML data in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my Android application, the user needs to scan the Indian Aadhar QR code. After reading the QR code it returns following response. I can not parse it. Please help me fix this

```
String xml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PrintLetterBarcodeData uid="00X575452391" 
    name="XX" 
    gender="M" 
    yob="1992" 
    gname="XX" 
    co="S/O: XX" 
    house="4-175" 
    street="XX" 
    lm="XX" 
    vtc="XX" 
    po="XX" 
    dist="XX" 
    subdist="XX" 
    state="" 
    pc="XX" 
    dob="XX/XX/XXXX"/>"
```

**Edit 1:** Added what I tried for XML parsing.

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java). But, it doesn't help me

```
    try{
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
        String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
        System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        System.out.println(je.toString());
    }
```

**Edit 2:** I have fixed it by myself using this code

```
public String xmlParser(String xml) {
    try{
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
        return xmlJSONObj.toString(0);
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

To use **XML.toJSONObject**, you will first need to download the java-json lib and include it in your project. You can use this link to find a downloadable jar:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm

Place downloaded the file in app/libs folder and add the dependency

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Then you can use the code

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not parse it"? Is the question simply how to parse xml? Then where is your code?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Show piece of code

Comment: Do not specify this kind of tags in your question tiitle you have to be specific to title that are related to technical terms like "Parsing of xml data in json format or whatso ever" specify do not specfiy the details unless you owned it or your is a part of your organisation if dont think "Adhhar" here is a product or something this can be misleading. Be carefull next time.

Comment: I mean, I can not do XML parsing, Because it does not have the proper format @f1sh

Comment: Edited my question. Please help me fix it

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? I only see an extra " at the end that may be a typo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64341259/8362967

Answer (score 0):

Check below link for your XML format (aadhaar card parsing).

https://github.com/GovindaPaliwal/Aadhaar-Card-Reader

> **Important Note** : This is old XML format (aadhaar card QR Code). UIDAI time to time update there QR Code Logic. Now a day they provide
>   2 type of QR code in card. i.e.
>
> 1. The large one contains your photograph & demographic information
> 2. Small one contains only your demographic information.
>
> Both are digitally signed by UIDAI.