# Is there any official jar file available to convert EDI X12(HIPPA) to JSON format

Tags: java, json, x12

Currently I am working on a project where we have to convert an EDI X12 file to a JSON file.

I didn't find anything related to this in google, can someone please help me with this?

I know there are some commercial mapping tools like Altova, but I require a jar file which I can use in my project directly.

Comment: Note that Altova does just generate code you can put into a jar.  If you don't really need to do much validation then look into the options below.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Google search gave me this:
https://github.com/BerryWorksSoftware/edi-json

You can also try using this (I'm not sure it supports JSON, but you can easily convert XML to JSON, [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java)): http://www.smooks.org/

Here is another great way with tutorial: https://www.progress.com/tutorials/xml-converters/converting-edi

Comment: @NikhilGandham Can you explain why it doesn't help, please?

Comment: it shows few errors in the code and pom file contains some unknown dependencies.Thank you

Comment: @NikhilGandham I updated my answer with additional solution.