# Android java xml very long to json

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I have to convert a very long xml file to a json.

I tried the following libraries, but none of them seems to work.

```
 - org.json:json:20180813 
 - com.github.javadev:underscore:1.38
```

Type file xml: [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/ExP2Mm2k)

Comment: Programmatically?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS: You intend to completely write a parse in java that allows you to convert an xml to json file.

Comment: Apple´s with apple´s.., Try work with XMLPullParser check this https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser

Comment: What does "very long" mean? 1Mb? 1Gb? 1Tb?

Comment: Not so heavy, we're talking about 200 KB. Example file is this: https://pastebin.com/raw/ExP2Mm2k

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use [online XML to JSON Converter](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html#ad-output)?  It is working for your xml file

Comment: The problem is that every day I have to do it, convert an xml to json.
Through an http call I have to recover a very long xml file and convert it to json.
For this, I look for a solution for android java.

Comment: have you tried the suggestions of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java

Comment: As I said I already tried the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823328/8024296
It seems to conflict with the normal org.json library.