# How can i send that soap api response some fields into db

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

How can I parse and send data fields to db using java. I need code for store data to db. It would require any extra dependencies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <WS_FulfillmentResponse xmlns="https://imfawstest.codemantra.com/AIDC/">
         <WS_FulfillmentResult>
            <Date_Generated>12/2/2019 2:24:03 AM</Date_Generated>
            <product>
               <PUB_ID>25905</PUB_ID>
               <LOG_NO>46725</LOG_NO>
               <PIN_NO>94389</PIN_NO>
               <SERIES_CODE>001</SERIES_CODE>
               <SERIES_DESC>IMF Working Papers</SERIES_DESC>
               <TITLE><![CDATA[cM_Safe and Wholesome Food - Nordic Reflections]]></TITLE>
               <SUBTITLE />
               <PUBL_SERIES_VOLNO>Working Paper No. 12/596</PUBL_SERIES_VOLNO>
               <LANGUAGE_ID>4</LANGUAGE_ID>
               <EDITION />
               <PRC_STATUS_ID>11</PRC_STATUS_ID>
               <PRC_STATUS_CODE>40</PRC_STATUS_CODE>
               <Process_Status_Desc>Key' metadata required for promotion is entered by now (Project ID &amp; description, Stock No.)</Process_Status_Desc>
               <PUBLISHED_DATE />
               <REVISION_DATE />
               <EST_COMPL_DATE />
               <ISBN>9781498302258</ISBN>
               <ISSN_ID>152</ISSN_ID>
               <COPYRIGHT_YR>2019</COPYRIGHT_YR>
               <DOI>10.5089/9781498302258.001</DOI>
               <Persistent_Link>https://elibrary.imf.org/view/IMF001/25905-9781498302258/25905-9781498302258/25905-9781498302258.xml</Persistent_Link>
               <SKU>802258</SKU>
               <DRAFT>0</DRAFT>
               <FRONT_MATTERS>0</FRONT_MATTERS>
               <MAIN>0</MAIN>
               <Size>Small</Size>
               <TOTAL>0</TOTAL>
               <ROMAN_ARABIC />
               <Dept_Phone>37779</Dept_Phone>
               <Dept_Email>JLI2</Dept_Email>
               <Dept_Contact_ID>22382</Dept_Contact_ID>
               <Dept_Contact_Name />
               <EXR_Editor_Name>Jim Beardow</EXR_Editor_Name>
               <EXR_Editor_ID>45</EXR_Editor_ID>
               <EXR_Editor_Phone>37899</EXR_Editor_Phone>
               <EXR_Editor_Email>jbeardow@imf.org</EXR_Editor_Email>
               <OutsidePublisher_Id>0</OutsidePublisher_Id>
               <OutsidePublisher_Name />
               <OutsidePublisher_Email />
               <OutsidePublisher_Phone />
               <OutsidePublisher_Address />
               <PUBL_MANUS_EXPT_DATE>10/31/2019</PUBL_MANUS_EXPT_DATE>
               <PUBL_DATE_TO_GRAPHICS />
               <PUBL_DATE_TRANSLATION_RECD />
               <PUBL_DATE_SENT_TRANSLATION>10/31/2019</PUBL_DATE_SENT_TRANSLATION>
               <PUBL_MANUS_RCVD_DATE>10/31/2019</PUBL_MANUS_RCVD_DATE>
               <PUBL_ASG_EDITOR_DATE>10/31/2019</PUBL_ASG_EDITOR_DATE>
               <FIRST_RECIEPT_DATE>10/31/2019</FIRST_RECIEPT_DATE>
               <PUBL_OUT_OF_PRINT_DATE />
               <PRIORITY>Medium</PRIORITY>
               <PUBL_DEPT_SUMMARY />
               <PUBL_NOTE_CORESP />
               <PUBL_INTERNAL_REMARKS />
```

above is sample format how to parse and take some fields name and isbn,price some more send to db how.

Comment: using org.json you can convert XML into JSON https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java

Comment: It's not ,i wanted to store the soap api response fields to my mongo database E.X:i call and got response from that response i wanted to store some fields into my db can you please help on that i am new of java using spring boot

Comment: you can filter your data after converting to JSON and store filtered JSON in mongo

Answer (score 0):

You can extract each data using inbuilt [Java API for XML Processing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html) called DOM XML Parser. It turns the XML file into DOM or Tree structure, and you have to traverse a node by node to get what you want. Here is an example that shows how to do it,

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

try {
     // Creating a constructor of file class and parsing an XML file
     File file = new File("XMLFile.xml");
     // An instance of factory that gives a document builder
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     // An instance of builder to parse the specified XML file
     DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = db.parse(file);
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
     System.out.println("Root element: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
     NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("product");

     // NodeList is not iterable, so we are using for loop
     for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
         Node node = nodeList.item(i);
         System.out.println("\nNode Name :" + node.getNodeName());
         if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
             Element eElement = (Element) node;
             System.out.println("PUB ID: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("PUB_ID").item(0).getTextContent());
             System.out.println("LOG NO: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("LOG_NO").item(0).getTextContent());
             System.out.println("PIN NO: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("PIN_NO").item(0).getTextContent());
             System.out.println("SERIES CODE: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("SERIES_CODE").item(0).getTextContent());
             System.out.println("SERIES DESC: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("SERIES_DESC").item(0).getTextContent());
         }
     }
 } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

And then you can code an insert query to send data to your database.

Hope this helps you!