# How to parse XML with data into DB in Spring?

Tags: java, xml, spring, database, xml-parsing

An XML file is passed to the application as input, in which the relative position of items (Item) and boxes (Box) is specified.  The boxes can be empty or contain items or other boxes. Items may not be in the box. How can I parse it into DB tables in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

````
Assuming your XML looks something like this, 



 ```<boxes>
        <box>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <name>test</name>
                </item>
            </items>
        </box>
    </boxes>
````

````
    
    As a first step what we can do is to parse and convert it to JSON using org.json maven dependency,
    
    ```JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);```
    
    you can find more details here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java
    
    As third step you can iterate over the JSONArray of boxes and items which looks something like this,
    
    ```{
      "boxes`enter code here`": {
        "box": {
          "items": {
            "item": {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "test"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
````

and put these in your desired database!

Comment: Thanks! id in my XML file is tag attribute